# Sharing auxiliary data between projects using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.2.0 and I want to share auxiliary data between projects but I could't find how to do that.

I tried to "play" with **auxiliary layer export** but there is no **auxiliary layer import**.

Also I tried and just duplicated and renamed **.qgd** file of the first project but no solution.

See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is "auxiliary data" for you?

Comment: @ErikLohmann I changed XY position of labels using auxiliary layers, I want to use the same positions in another project and I don't want to do the same manual work second time.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you there. Why did you use layers to position your labels, and didn't simply work with the properties-settings?

Comment: @ErikLohmann it is an annotation layer. What I am doing needs such actions. I am just curious if it possible what I asked above.

Comment: It seems you're trying to use auxiliary data in a way not intended by the QGIS developers. Auxiliary data is not designed to be transferred between QGIS projects. If you need to do so, do it the way eurojam suggested by saving each auxiliary storage field as an attribute table field. Then use those fields for data-defined label positions in the new project.

Comment: While auxiliary data may not be designed to be transferred between QGIS projects, it is still sometimes necessary, as for example when updating a project to a new version of QGIS if the new version handles auxiliary storage differently (this was my problem, anyway). In situations where the users are inexperienced with GIS software, having label position data stored in attributes can be very confusing and detrimental to the project.

Comment: I guess this feature request is what you would need. After some research, it seems to me that this is not easily possible. Not even within the the same project from one layer to another. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44765

Answer (score 4):

you can move the data stored in the auxiliary storage with the field calculator into your dataset:

[image: screenshot from field calculator]

Comment: what you say doesn't relate with another project. If you copy that layer into another project you won't see those auxiliary fields anymore.

Comment: that is right. but you can use them furthermore for datadefined positions of the labeling

Comment: but in this way you are creating and creating new fields, that is not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem just now, with the added difficulty of trying to move auxiliary data (label locations) from a project in QGIS 3.16 to another project in QGIS 3.28. The trick is to understand that a `.qgz` project file [is actually a zip archive of (usually) two other files](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.html#qgs-qgz-the-qgis-project-file-format): a `.qgs` project XML file, and a `.qgd` auxiliary sqlite database file. That means that if we unzip a `.qgz` file, we can access its auxiliary data database and modify it as necessary.

Here are step-by-step instructions for copying label position auxiliary layers from one project file in QGIS 3.16 (`P1.qgz`) to a second project file in QGIS 3.28 (`P2.qgz`):

###### 1. Make QGIS create the auxiliary label position layers in `P2.qgz`

- Open `P2.qgz`
- Select the layer with the labels of interest, and go to `Layer Properties > Labels > Placement > Data Defined`, and check the "Store Data In Project" box **for both X and Y**, then click OK
- Use the Move Label tool on a label in that layer
- Follow the prompt to choose the key
- Move the label once
- Select the layer again and go to `Layer Properties > Fields` to ensure that the auxiliary label position layers have been created
- Save `P2.qgz` and close QGIS

###### 2. Unzip the project files

- Copy `P1.qgz` and `P2.qgz` to a separate folder
- Using [7Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or another compression utility, extract the contents of the copies of P1.qgz and P2.qgz - each one should contain a `.qgs` file (project information in XML) and a `.qgd` file (auxiliary database)

  - Side Note: It seems that at some point after QGIS 3.16, some project information was migrated into a new `oyJZbS_styles.db` file, so you may see that, too

###### 3. Access and modify the auxiliary data using a SQLITE Database Manager

- Download and install [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) (any SQLite DBMS should work)
- Open DB Browser, click `Open Database`, and select `P1.qgd`
- Open a second instance of DB Browser, click `Open Database`, and select `P2.qgd`
- In the DB Browser window with `P2.qgd`, select the table containing your label position data and delete it
- In the DB Browser window with `P1.qgd`, select the table containing your label position data and drag it into the window with `P2.qgd`
- In the DB Browser window with `P2.qgd`, click `Write Changes` to save your changes to file, and close DB Browser

###### 4. Re-zip the project files

- Select all of the P2 files and use your compression utility to compress them back into a zip archive (`P2-new.qgz`)
- Move `P2-new.qgz` back to its original folder, and open it up to test that the label position data is being interpreted correctly. If it is, replace the old `P2.qgz` file with the new one.